# FQL query by name

Tags: sql, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm looking for a way of doing somethig similar to the following query, but I'm getting stuck into the Facebook constraints.

```
SELECT page_id,name,latitude,longitude 
FROM place 
WHERE name LIKE 'my favorite restaurant'
```

After googling for a while, I discovered that:

- FQL doesn't supports LIKE clauses;
- I could use `strpos(name, 'my favorite restaurat') > 0`, but it (seems to) turn the collumn non-indexable; Even name being indexed (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/)
- I'm looking for alternatives such as wildcards (*, ?, some regex), or;
- Some kind of nested queries.

I'm wondering that should exist such a way of doing so, because the some Facebook Android SDK screens supports this query mechanism.

Thanks!

Comment: The closest thing is `WHERE CONTAINS('my favorite restaurant')`. It's an undocumented function that searches more than just the name. It seems to be optimized for whole words.

Comment: WOW! it looks like this command will fit my needs. Thanks a lot!